# Error how to print array of char in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    char buffer[256];
    strcpy(buffer, "see");
    int size = strlen(buffer);
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++, size--){
      char temp = buffer[i];
      buffer[i] = buffer[size];
      buffer[size] = temp;
   }
   printf("Inversa %s\n",buffer);

}
```

The code dont print anything and i dont know why. If anyone can help me

Comment: `buffer[size]` is `'\0'` when first time. `buffer[i] = buffer[size];` => `buffer[0] = '\0';`

Answer (score 1):

Since your `i` depends on `size`, do not modify it, instead take another variable, say `l`, and use it instead. Also, size of the string will be from `0` to `size-1`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
char buffer[256];
strcpy(buffer, "see");

int size = strlen(buffer);
int l=size-1;
 for(int i = 0; i < size/2; i++, l--){
      char temp = buffer[i];
  buffer[i] = buffer[l];
  buffer[l] = temp;

 }
 printf("Inversa %s\n",buffer);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, `buffer[size]` contains null character. And with your current code you fill `buffer` with nulls. Also, to reverse elements of array you should in loop go to `size/2` instead of `size`. To reverse chars in array you could use following simple code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    char buffer[256];
    strcpy(buffer, "see");
    int size = strlen(buffer);
   for(int i = 0; i < size/2; i++){
      char temp = buffer[i];
      buffer[i] = buffer[size-1-i];
      buffer[size-1-i] = temp;
   }
   printf("Inversa %s\n",buffer);
}
```

Comment: You never modify `size`, wouldn't you keep replacing the last character (`buffer[size]=temp;`) over and over again, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Because string in C ends with `\0`, in the for cycle you push it to the start at first
This could be ok (but not tested)

```
  char temp = buffer[i];
  buffer[i] = buffer[size-1];
  buffer[size-1] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change line 10 and 11 of your code to :

```
buffer[i] = buffer[size-1];
buffer[size-1] = temp;
```

Reason is because value of variable 'size' is 3. so when you access buffer[size], It points to buffer[3] which is string termination character '\0'. Your buffer is filled only till buffer[2].
Example :

```
buffer[0]='s'
buffer[1]='e'
buffer[2]='e'
buffer[3]='\0'
```

buffer[3] marks the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one error in your code (invalid access of array, buffer[3]).

You need to change the line:

```
int size = strlen(buffer);
```

to

```
int size = strlen(buffer)-1;
```

or use `buffer[size-1]` instead of `buffer[size]`